# c++ Two Classes Refering To Each Other

Tags: c++, oop

i'm working with c++. 
I need to create two classes that refering to each other.
Something like this:

```
class A {
  private:
    B b; 
   //etc...
};
class B {
  private:
    A a; 
   //etc...
};
```

How can i do that?
Sorry for my bad English and thanks you for helping me :)

Comment: can you explain the problem in more detail? btw you can use forward declaration to avoid circular compilation dependency

Comment: Check this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do that even in principle, because a single `A` object would contain a `B` which contains another `A`, which contains *another* `B` and *another* `A` ...

If you just want a *reference*, you can simply do

```
class B; // forward declaration

class A {
  B& b_;  // reference
public:
  explicit A(B& b) : b_(b) {}
};

class B {
  A a_;
public:
  B() : a_(*this) {}
};
```

Now each `B` contains an `A` which refers to the `B` in which it sits.

Do note however that you can't really do anything with `b` (or `b_`) inside `A`'s constructor, because the object it refers to hasn't finished creating itself yet.

A pointer would also work - and of course `A` and `B` can both have references instead of `B` containing an immediate object.

Comment: Realy realy thanks tou :)